# overide parent method is not working properly

Tags: java

I need to calculate tax for a object wine i have it calculated in parent class and now i need to calculate it in class wine because i have additional tax now i have this super.

```js
super.novaCijena(cijenaPr*ALC_TAX);
```

but i need it to be like this

```js
super.novaCijena(cijenaPr)*ALC_TAX;
```

here is my curent code

main class

```js
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Chocolate c= new Chocolate("Crna Čokolada", 10.5, 1254120, 200);
        System.out.println(c);
        
        Wine w= new Wine("Crno vino", 5.00, 0125452, 25);
        System.out.println(w);
    }
```

Product class

```js
public abstract class Product 
{
    public String nazivProizvoda;
    public int barKod;
    public double cijenaPr;
    public final double pDV=1.2;
    //public double novaCijena;
        
    public Product (String nazivProizvoda, int barKod, double cijenaPr)
    {
        this.nazivProizvoda=nazivProizvoda;
        this.barKod=barKod;
        this.cijenaPr=cijenaPr;
    }


    public double novaCijena(double cijenaPr)
    {
         double novaCijena=this.cijenaPr*pDV;
        return novaCijena;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Proizvod: " + this.nazivProizvoda + ", " + "cijena: " + novaCijena(cijenaPr)
               + ", " + "bar kod: " + this.barKod;
    }
```

and wine class

```js
public class Wine extends Product
{
    public double zapremina;
    public final double ALC_TAX=1.1;
    //public double pDV;
    public Wine (String nazivProizvoda, double cijenaPr, int barKod, double zapremina)
    {

        
        super(nazivProizvoda,barKod,cijenaPr);
        this.zapremina=zapremina;
        //this.pDV=pDV;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
 
        super.novaCijena(cijenaPr*ALC_TAX);
            return super.toString() + ", " + "zapremina: " + zapremina + " ml.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This is Java and thus completely unrelated to JavaScript, jQuery, HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to have an overriden method in Wine:

```
@Override
public double novaCijena(double cijenaPr) {
    return super.novaCijena(cijenaPr) * ALC_TAX;
}
```

And call `this.novaCijena(cijenaPr)` inside Wine.